# Show that the McNuggets ring $A=\mathbb C[z^6,z^9,z^{20}]$ is not a UFD

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $A=\mathbb C[z^6,z^9,z^{20}]$ be the McNuggets ring. Is $A$ a unique factorisation domain?

I'm reading a solution to this question and it says,

No, since $z^{12}=z^6z^6=z^4z^4z^4$ which are two distinct factorisations so $A$ is not a UFD.

Firstly I want to ask is this ring essentially the ring of polynomials with $z^6,z^9,z^{20}$ as variables with coefficients in $\mathbb C$? If so then how can $z^4\in A$?

And secondly why does $z^{12}=z^6z^6=z^4z^4z^4$ imply it's not a UFD? Is it because $z^6$ and $z^4$ are irreducible in $A$? If so why? Thanks!

Comment: It sounds like a typo / thinko in the book, but the result still holds — consider $z^{18} = z^9\times z^9 = z^6\times z^6\times z^6$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like there may really have been a 9-piece McNuggets in the 80’s, but given the circumstances I’m inclined to think someone sloppily copied a 4 into a 9.  That would fix all your problems.

Notice that a factorization in this ring would also be a factorization in $\mathbb C[z]$, so that limits factorizations to powers of $z$.

$z^4$ is clearly irreducible, since it is the lowest positive power of $z$ you can produce.

$z^6$ is higher, but the only candidate for a factor is $z^4$, and $z^2$ isn't available. So it's also irreducible.